# Magento - How to set Payment Information in backend for a custom Payment module

Tags: php, magento

I have created a custom Payment module but I could only display the following information in the admin side of Magento

Type of Card

Card Number : xxxx-last 4 digits

Order was placed using USD

But how can I get other details just liek in case pf Paypal like,

Card Validation Status:

Address Validation Status:

Last Transaction ID:

etc. I am getting all these response from my custom payment gateway but I don't know what function to call or how to display it in the back-end for the store owner to see.

Can any one help me with this? Right now my payment module is doing `authorize_capture` as the payment action so I have `Model/PaymentMethod.php` which has `function capture(Varien Object payment, amount)` to deal with the logic. So can I set the Payment Information from there or do I need to create any other files?

Please let me know.

EDIT: I found partial answer to what I need doing.

http://nicholas.piasecki.name/blog/2009/10/add-avs-and-cvn-to-magentos-admin-screen-in-just-637-easy-steps/#comment-1043

But I am not able to override a default admin template file. This link tells to create a Block file which overrides Mage/Payment/Block/Info and set a template in there to be used.

But its not reading it. Can some one tell me the correct way to override an admin template file so that future upgrades don't overwrite it.

I hope some one must be familiar with this bit now.

it isn't taking the code from my overriden module Block file. The template file I need to over ride is app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/payment/default/info.phtml. Using the link mentioned I have already overridden Mage/Payment/Block/Info and wrote my own code but am not able to set and point towards my template. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a good article by Alan Storm which will show you how to add settings to the backend:

http://alanstorm.com/custom_magento_system_configuration

Comment: Thanks but the thing I dont want to add a custom tab in the Admin. I would like to add payment information to my orders if they are using my custom payment module. So when I view Sales > Orders > Order 1000000100 then in the 'Payment Information' section I should be able to see all payment info details my custom gateway sent me in its response. How do I do that?

Comment: I found a link http://nicholas.piasecki.name/blog/2009/10/add-avs-and-cvn-to-magentos-admin-screen-in-just-637-easy-steps/#comment-1043 which almost does what I want to do but just the point where I need to override default adminhtml template, it isn't taking the code from my overriden module Block file. The template file I need to over ride is `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/payment/default/info.phtml`. Using the link mentioned I have already overridden `Mage/Payment/Block/Info` and wrote my own code but am not able to set and point towards my template. Any Ideas?